# Upload Terraform Plan to S3 Bucket via GitHub Actions

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, github-actions, cicd

I am working on a `CI/CD pipeline` in GitHub I run `terraform plan >> plan.txt` and want the plan to be saved into an existing `S3 bucket` for logging purposes. What is the best way to do this?

I am aware of existing extensions on the GitHub marketplace, in particular, one called `S3 Sync`, but I suspect it's too large-scale for me as I only want to upload a single `plan.txt` file instead of a website

I also considered uploading the item from the `main.tf` file but the issue is that the Terraform code is run first and the plan is produced after so it won't have access to `plan.txt`

Please let me know if there is any information I can provide that can help

Comment: You can use AWS CLI to upload a file, using `aws s3 cp`, but you would have to install it if not present in the image.

Comment: I would think there is a GH action for copying artifacts to S3. This exists in other pipeline tools, and GH actions is rather well supported.

Comment: I would recommend looking into https://atlantis.io/ before rolling your own TF CI solution.

Comment: If you're using hosted runner you have `aws cli` preinstalled on it. Check specific OS for full list of tools: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software